# Quoted vs unquoted string expansion

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, echo, whitespace

1. `for i in $(xrandr); do echo  "$i" ; done`
2. `for i in "$(xrandr)"; do echo "$i"; done`
3. `for i in "$(xrandr)"; do echo $i; done`

I understand why 1 differs from 2. But why does 3 give a different output from 2? Please explain the output too. How do quotes work on newlines?

Comment: Related: [When is double-quoting necessary?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Comment: See also [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An unquoted variable (as in `$var`) or command substitution (as in `$(cmd)` or `` `cmd` ``) is the *split+glob* operator in Bourne-like shells.

That is, their content is split according to the current value of the `$IFS` special variable (which by default contains the space, tab and newline characters)

And then each word resulting of that splitting is subject to *filename generation* (also known as *globbing* or *filename expansion*), that is, they are considered as patterns and are expanded to the list of files that match that pattern.

So in `for i in $(xrandr)`, the `$(xrandr)`, because it's not within quotes, is split on sequences of space, tab and newline characters. And each word resulting of that splitting is checked for matching file names (or left as is if they don't match any file), and `for` loops over them all.

In `for i in "$(xrandr)"`, we're not using the split+glob operator as the *command substitution* is quoted, so there's one pass in the loop on **one** value: the output of `xrandr` (without the trailing newline characters which *command substitution* strips).

However in `echo $i`, `$i` is unquoted again, so again the content of `$i` is split and subject to *filename generation* and those are passed as separate arguments to the `echo` command (and `echo` outputs its arguments separated by spaces).

So lesson learnt:

- if you don't want *word splitting* or *filename generation*, always quote variable expansions and command substitutions
- if you do want *word splitting* or *filename generation*, leave them unquoted but set `$IFS` accordingly and/or enable or disable filename generation if needed (`set -f`, `set +f`).

Typically, in your example above, if you want to loop over the blank separated list of words in the output of `xrandr`, you'd need to:

- leave `$IFS` at its default value (or unset it) to split on blanks
- Use `set -f` to disable filename generation unless you're sure that `xrandr` never outputs any `*` or `?` or `[` characters (which are wildcards used in filename generation patterns)

And then only use the split+glob operator (only leave command substitution or variable expansion unquoted) in the `in` part of the `for` loop:

```
set -f; unset -v IFS
for i in $(xrandr); do whatever with "$i"; done
```

If you want to loop over the (non-empty) *lines* of the `xrandr` output, you'd need to set `$IFS` to the newline character:

```
IFS='
'
```

Answer (score 4):

A quoted newline is a newline. So `echo "$1"` gives a single command line argument to echo, which then prints the newlines directly.

An unquoted newline is whitespace. So `echo $1` gives many command line arguments to echo, which prints them one after another separated with spaces.

Comment: _An unquoted newline is whitespace_ is a bit too much of a short-cut to be really useful as an explanation of the behaviour here IMO.