# Why asterisk in command result in for loop is expanding?

Tags: shell, wildcards, git, command-substitution

I want to write a script that will run

```
git diff --name-status master..<BRANCH>
```

but when I run this:

```
for i in $(git branch | grep -v master); do
   echo $i;
done
```

I get echo one directory because `git branch` echo asterisk (I have one directory in current directory)

```
* <SELECTED BRANCH>
```

Why `*` is expanded and how can I prevent that expansion?

**UPDATE**: I can prevent this by using this:

```
for i in $(git branch | tr -d '*' | grep -v master);
done;
```

But why is this happening? Why I need to remove asterisk?

Comment: You are missing `quotes`  `" "`

Comment: @val0x00ff where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unquoted variables and command substitutions like `$i` or `$(git …)` apply the [split+glob operator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78914/quoted-vs-unquoted-string-expansion/78924#78924) to the string result. That is:

1. Build a string containing the value of the variable or the output of the command (minus final newlines in the latter case).
2. Split the string into separate fields according to the value of [`IFS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator).
3. Interpret each field as a wildcard pattern and replace it by the list of matching file names; if a pattern doesn't match any file, leave it intact.

The output of `git branch | grep -v master` (step 1) contains `* master` which is split (step 2) into two fields `*` and `master`; `*` is replaced (step 3) by the list of file names in the current directory.

You can run `set -f` to temporarily disable globbing. Another approach is to avoid command substitution and instead [parse the input with `read`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/150939). Neither do the right thing though — you'll have spurious branch names, because the git output contains more than what you need (the `*` flag to indicate the current branch, but also things like `remotes/somewhere/foo -> bar` for remote-tracking branches). I think the following is safe if inelegant:

```
for i in $(git branch | sed -e 's/^..//' -e 's/ .*//'); do
   echo $i
done
```

I think the robust way is to use [`git-for-each-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-for-each-ref.html).

```
for i in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads refs/remotes); do
  echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

[Text streams like this should be read using a `while` loop rather than `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), which is probably causing the issue (although I cannot reproduce it). A simple way to do this:

```
git branch | while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "${line:2}"
done
```

Comparison:

```
$ cd -- "$(mktemp -d)"
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/tmp.MJFmu7q7EH/.git/
$ touch README
$ git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial commit"
[master (root-commit) da46b03] Initial commit
$ git branch foo
$ git branch
  foo
* master
$ for i in $(git branch)
> do
>    echo $i
> done
foo
*
master
$ git branch | while IFS= read -r line
> do
>     echo "${line:2}"
> done
foo
master
```

Comment: Have the same with `while`, I'm using `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`.