# Implementing a command that executes the given command in a certain path and returns to the current path

Tags: bash, alias

my code:

```
execInPath() {
prev_dir=${PWD##*/}
cd $1
shift
res=$($@)
cd prev_dir
echo res
}
alias path=execInPath
```

`$ path ~ ls` gives:
`bash: cd: prev_dir: No such file or directory`
(and the files in my home directory prior to that)

Comment: `cd $prev_dir` instead of `cd prev_dir`; maybe also `echo $res`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `"$prev_dir"` to reference variable `prev_dir`:

```
execInPath() {
  prev_dir=${PWD##*/}
  cd -P -- "$1"
  shift
  res=$( "$@" )
  cd -- "$prev_dir"
  printf '%s\n' "$res"
}

alias path=execInPath
```

But using a subshell is easier:

```
execInPath() {
  : 'Change directory in subshell'
  (
    cd -- "$1" || return 1
    shift
    res=$( "$@" )
    printf '%s\n' "$res"
  )
  : 'Back to previous dir'
  pwd
}

alias path=execInPath
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a subshell:

```
execInPath() (cd -P -- "$1" && shift && exec "$@")
```

Notes:

- You need to check the exit status of `cd` as if `cd` fails, you'd run the command in the wrong directory.
- if you want `cd` to behave like in other languages, you need `-P`.
- think of the exit status of your function. Here, you want it to be unsuccessful if `cd` fails, and be the exit status of `"$@"` otherwise.
- `$@` must be quoted always.
- It's impossible to do `cd some-dir;...;cd original-dir` and get back to the same original directory 100% reliably.

Comment: This also came into my mind at first, but it seems that the OP want to do other things inside function after go back to previous dir.

Comment: Would you mind explaining more details about *behave like in other languages*, what's other languages?

Comment: @cuonglm, the chdir or C, perl, python, ruby, java, you name it.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a variable in bash, there is no $ (unlike perl), but when you use/refer to a variable in bash, you need to add the $ to it. Your `cd prev_dir` should be `cd $prev_dir`.

Comment: `cd $prev_dir` doesn't make sense. It should be at least `cd "$prev_dir"` or rather `cd -P -- "$prev_dir"`.

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't make sense. The quotes are not required. `export prev_dir="/bin";cd $prev_dir` works just fine.

Comment: @TimS.: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/38906 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/38906

Comment: See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346), [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766), [When is double-quoting necessary?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694), [Expansion of a shell variable and effect of glob and split on it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108963), [Quoted vs unquoted string expansion](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78914)...

Comment: While I agree that it's a security issue, that's far from "doesn't make sense". Personally I don't use bash for a number of reasons, but that's beside the point. Thanks for the links.

Comment: It makes as little sense as writing `chdir(glob(split($prev_dir)))` in another language. The equivalent of `chdir($var)` is `cd -P -- "$var"` (except when `$var` contains `-`).