# What is variable substitution in shell programming

Tags: shell, variable-substitution

This question is very basic and I ask it not only for myself but for other newcomers who see the term *variable substitution* and have the following thoughts:

As far as I understand, the term *variable substitution* describes "substituting a value of a variable in another" but I doubt that's correct.
I wondered why this action requires a special term instead just saying "changing a variable's value with editing it manually in a text editor?

What is *variable substitution* concept in shell programming and if you know the answer, please give a practical example for what types of actions it uses you in your work.

Comment: When answering the question "Why does `echo '$PWD'` print `$PWD` and not my current directory?" here on U&L, I need the term _variable substitution_ to be able to say "It's because variable substitution doesn't happen within single-quoted strings."

Comment: I believe that this is because the expansions and substitutions are only _in part_ variables.  Brace expansion (`for i in {1..10};`) and glob expansion (`for file in dir/*log;`) for example, fall under the same umbrella as expansion of variables (`for arg in "$@";`) or subshells (`for ip in $(awk '$1 !~ /^#/ {print $1}' /etc/hosts);`.

Comment: I edited the question more than 2 years after asking it to make the phrasing better; if the downvoter knew that - I personally think downvoting was a wrong move.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> substituting a value of a given variable in another.

That description is wrong on several counts. Variable substitution replaces the **name** of a variable (plus some syntactic fluff) by its **value**. Furthermore, it does not operate “in” a variable, but in a command. The command could be one that sets the value of a variable, but that's just one case among many.

For example, the command `echo $foo` displays the value of the variable. The source code contains `$foo`, and the corresponding output contains the value of the variable `foo`.

The reason this is called “variable substitution” is that the shell operates by a series of transformations of strings (and lists of strings). For example (simplified), consider the command `ls -l $dir/*.$ext`. To evaluate it, several things happen in sequence:

1. The shell starts to parse the command and splits it into three words: `ls`, `-l` and `$dir/*.$ext`.
2. In the third word, the shell sees two variable substitutions to perform (that's what the dollar signs mean in this context). Say that the value of `dir` is `/some/path` and the value of `ext` is `txt`, then the shell rewrites `$dir/*.$ext` to `/some/path/*.txt`. This is a substitution because the value of each variable is substituted for the dollar-name syntax.
3. The shell expands the wildcard pattern `/some/path/*.txt` to the list of matching file names.
4. The shell executes `ls` with the arguments that it's computed.

(The syntax `$foo` [does more than substitute the value of a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78914/quoted-vs-unquoted-string-expansion) but that's another story.)

In most programming languages, to take the value of a variable, you just write the variable's name. The shell is designed for interactive use; if you write a name it's interpreted as a literal string. That's why the syntax to take the value of a variable has an extra marker to say “I want to take a variable's value”.

> why this action requires a special term instead just saying "changing a variable's value with editing it manually in a text editor?

Variable substitution has nothing to do with changing the value of a variable. Changing the value of a variable is an [assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)).

Of course an assignment can contain variable substitutions, like any other command. But variable substitutions are not designed specifically for assignments.

Furthermore you can't change the value of a variable with an editor. An already declared variable has a value in each process, it isn't a system configuration. You can have configuration files that set the *initial* value of a variable, and you can use an editor to change that initial value in those files, but after that the value can change.